# Benefits from using void pointers as FFI interface type

Tags: c++, c, ffi

I'm writing a simple wrapper for the C++ library. I have following type that is describing successful result or error:

```
template<typename T>
struct Result
{
    T value;
    const char* error;

    static Result<T> FromFunction(std::function<T()> function)
    {
        Result<T> result = {};
        try
        {
            result.value = function();
        }
        catch( cv::Exception& e )
        {
            const char* err_msg = e.what();
            auto len = std::strlen(err_msg);
            auto retained_err = new char[len + 1];
            std::strcpy(retained_err, err_msg);
            result.error = retained_err;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

And I use it:

```
extern "C" {
   Result<double> foo() {
      ...
      return result;
   }
}
```

**It works fine with GCC** (this function gets called and returns correct results), however, msvc gets very upset because of template parameter as function return type:

```
error C2526: 'foo': C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'CResult<double>'
```

I wrote following workaround and it seems to work, but I'm not sure about `void*` in public interface:

```
void* foo() { {
    return &result;
}
```

Is it considered a bad practice? Because I'd like to follow DRY principle and do not write a lot or wrappers such as ResultDouble, ResultInt and so on.

Comment: Could `CResult<double> foo()` even be used in C (assuming we use a compiler that allows the declaration)?

Comment: @user2079303 i'm not sure about C, but it works fine when imported in rust code.  `T` is always some primitive type thus return type size is known at compile time and layout is constant. It makes this interface stable and usable.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return the return type of the function rather than a Result (or CResult, there seems to be some discrepancy there).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir sorry, I don't understand your point. My idea is: I have set of `Result<some_type_here>` with some instantiations but I can't `export C` functions that returns such a type in msvc. So I need some workaround here. returning `void*` is one of them, but probably there's something better.

Comment: You may want to remove the `C` tag since the C language doesn't have templates.

Comment: One problem may be that by returning the address of the `struct` as a `void *` via an `extern "C"` linked function, you lose the actual `struct` itself.  Where is it?  Are you returning the address of a local object?  Thinking out loud here: maybe you can add a destructor to the object that emits the address contained in `this`?  If that address is the same as the value in the `void *` you return, that'd indicate you're returning the address of a local copy of the `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem with MSVC, but it seems to be happy if you use an output parameter (at least on MSVC19-RTW, the version available on godbolt)

```
extern "C" 
{
   void foo( Result<double> * res ) {
      //....
      *res = {};
   }
}
```

Comment: I ended with replacing all results with void functions and output parameters. Looks hacky but at least I don't have to instantinate all teplates manually.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have templates, so your compiler is right to complain/error.

You're kind of in a strange use case, because *technically* your function foo has a fully defined type, and you could export it (say in a library) with C linkage. However, any C compiler reading that code section is going to vomit, because C compiler's aren't supposed to know what a template is.